# Lodash, call functions in a loop and return first matching result

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash

I want to iterate through an array of objects, calling a method on them. If the result of that method meets some condition. I want to return that result immediately. I've written this:

```
public getFirstMatch(value: string, allValues: string[]): Result {
    let foundResult = undefined;
    _.find(this.myArrayofMatchers, matcher => {
        let result = matcher.isMatch(value, allValues);
        if(result.isMatch){
            foundResult = result;
            return true;
        }
    })

    return foundResult || new Result(false);
}
```

It works but it seems clunky and unclear. `_.find`, imho, isn't an clear indicator of what I'm trying to do as I don't care about the actual `matcher`. The fact `foundResult` needs to exist is something I find quite ugly. And it seems longer that it needs to be. **Is there something I could do better here? Is there a better lodash function for this?**

Incidentally, here's what I had in mind, using a for loop

```
public isMatch(value: string, allValues: string[]): Result {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.myArrayofMatchers.length; i++){
        let result = this.myArrayofMatchers[i].isMatch(value, allValues);
        if (result.isMatch) {
            return result;
        }
    }
    return new Result(false);
}
```

Comment: Does `for (var matcher of _myArrray)` work?

Comment: @georg Do you mean foreach? I've heard using lodash is better practice and I'm concerned about efficiency (I know, stupid language choice). `for (let i = 0; i < this.checkers.length; i++){` work, which is what I'm using right now.

Comment: No, I mean the `for..of` loop which works exactly like in your second snippet. No need to use a library if an ordinary language construct works.

Comment: @georg Ahhhhh, I hadn't heard of that. Cheers, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a `_.find` like a `_.foreach`. It's bad. Lodash find returns value, so you should take advantage of it.

Your method should look like this:

```
public getFirstMatch(value: string, allValues: string[]): Result {
    const foundResult = _.find(
        this.myArrayofMatchers,
        matcher => matcher.isMatch(value, allValues).isMatch
    );

    return foundResult || new Result(false);
}
```